# Regex for a decimal range

Tags: regex

iam trying to build a simple regex for a range of decimals, but for some reason i am having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to work with the period. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Numbers:

3.5 - 4.3

My non working regex:

> (3.5-4.3)

Comment: `(3.5-4.3)` is looking for the literal `3.5-4.3` and capturing it. I wouldnt call that a regex, what language are you using this in?

Comment: ya, i did something like (3\.5-4\.3) with no luck. From what i read, regex's are notoriously bad for doing number ranges. I know there must be an easier way.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a regex?

Comment: @chris85 i am just testing it on regex and have been trying different variations on there.

Comment: @melpomene its looking for certain application patch level. And this seemed like the easiest way to do what iam trying to accomplish

Comment: a dash is not giving you a range in regex, that's totally the wrong approach

Comment: Maybe `^(3\.[5-9]\d*|4(?:\.(?:[0-2]|3)\d*)?)$` is what you'd want? Depending on where you are using this that may need to be modified.

Comment: "a simple regex for a range of decimals" - I am afraid there is no such a thing, regex is not aware of numbers at all. It is only concerned with strings - even when doing `[1-9]` regex does not treat 1 and 9 as numbers but as character literals. There is a way you could force it, but i would't call it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the input BroiSatse, thats what i was afraid of. I was hoping for something simple, but it got exponentially more complicated when i started working with decimals.

Comment: @chris85 ill give this a shot

Comment: The main question is as always: what is it what you are trying to achieve? If you are trying to validate input, parse the string first to extract the number and then validate it is in the correct range.

Comment: @JohnDoe Integers are best dealt with as integers, not with a regex, as you can see from the regex I've shown just 2 numbers is much more work than `$x >= 3.5 && $x <= 4.3`.

Comment: @chris85 that is exactly what i wanted, but the tool iam using won't support something like that unfortunately.But it does support regexs. Its a bit of a pain :/

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: @chris85 it's a security tool, unfortunately I can't disclose it

Comment: @chris85 I'll keep u posted on if your regex will work. I'll post whatever the solution we get to the board here

Comment: Well what language is it running or regex engine?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question you asked is:

```
^(3\.[5-9]\d*|4(?:\.(?:[0-2]\d*|3))?)$
```

Your regex would attempt to capture the value `3.5-4.3`. `()` is a capture group and captures whatever is inside it. A `-` in regex outside of a character class has no special meaning.

The provided regex is looking for an full match of the string because of the anchors `^$`, then either `3.5X` through `3.9X` (X being any number of digits), `4` by itself, `4.0X` through `4.2X`, or `4.3`.

The ranges are allowed in character class and go through the ascii table, so it might include more than you expect. e.g. `A-z` includes symbols, `a-Z` is invalid, and `a-z` is `a` through `z`.

You didn't provide the tool you are using so additional help can't be given. The `\d` might not be supported, but can be changed to `[0-9]`.

A possibly better/cleaner approach to this could be capturing the integer then comparing it in whatever language you are using.

```
`^\d+\.?\d*$`
```

then something like (PHP demonstration):

```
if($match[0] >= 3.5 && $match[0] <= 4.3)
     echo 'Valid number';
```

**Update:**

Depending on the engine being used this might be better,

```
^(3\.[5-9][0-9]*|4(\.([0-2][0-9]*|3))?)$
```